# the following packages have unmet dependencies: python3-tornado: breaks mitmproxy

Tags: linux

What is the problem, when I try to install openvas it says "[the following packages have unmet dependencies: python3-tornado: breaks mitmproxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKlU0.jpg)" when I try to install python3-tornado "the following packages have unmet dependencies gsettings -desctop-schemas: breaks: mutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM2lT.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The entire error log isn’t readable. Edit your question and include the text.

Comment: The error is also pretty straightforward. What's your exact question here?